# simulate a function with vhdl code by ISE

Tags: vhdl

I've started to learn VHDL recently. I write a piece of VHDL code to determine the arith

statement,but it doesn't work. Actually when I simulate it, the output does not

change and it remains 0.0. I don't know where my mistake is. Do I need to use a

external clock? When I do it, it does not change :-(

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

package mypack is
    type real_vector is array (integer range <>) of real;
end mypack;

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
--use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use work.mypack.all;

entity convolution is port (
    x:in real_vector(0 to 3);
    y:in real_vector(0 to 1);

    f:out real_vector (0 to 4)
);
end convolution;

architecture Behavioral of convolution is
    --signal temp : real_vector (0 to 4):= (others => 0.0);
    --signal enable : std_logic :='0';
begin
    process (x,y)
        variable sum :real;
    begin

        for n in f'range loop
            enable <= '0';
            for k in y'range loop
                sum:=sum + x(k)*y(n-k);
            end loop;
            -- temp(n) <= sum;
            f(n) <= sum ;
            sum:=0.0;
        end loop;

        enable <= '1';

        --if (enable'event and enable='1') then
        --    f <= temp;
        --end if;

    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: how do you simulate? if you have a testbench post it as well, otherwise its hard to tell the reason for the missbehavior in your simulation.

Comment: If you put an assert or report statement in the inner loop, does it report as often as you expect with the expected values of your variables?

Answer (score 0):

There are some things I can see in your code sample:

1. You use real types. You should avoid them because there are usually not synthesizable and only work in simulations. An alternative could be the use of [Fixed-Point arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).
2. You use variables. You should try to avoid using variables as long as you do not really know what you are doing bevause variables have a different behaviour than normal signals. Variables get their values assigned to immediately while signal values are assigned at the end of a process. Variables are therefore often used just to simplyfy more complex statements (like a `#define` statement in C for example).
3. You should make your design synchronous/clocked and use registers. Make one specific operation per clock cycle.

I think the statement `sum:=0.0` at the end of your main loop overwrites the value of sum in the assignment `f(n) <= sum`.

Answer (score 0):

VHDL is not a programming language, it's a hardware description language.

For this reason, it's important to use std_logic_vectors, unsigneds and other primitives that are native to the hardware in order to get reliable results and to optimize the final design a much as possible.

You are not seeing the output change because the entire for loop is executing completely in one iteration of the process. The final result is only going to be the last state of the for loop, which in this case, is `sum:=0.0;`. In order to fix this, it is highly recommended that you use an external clock in your design, and that clock is part of the sensitivity list of your process. this will allow you to use your process as a for loop inherently, which will remove the need for an explicit for loop altogether.

A question very similar to this one came up on the EE stack exchange site few days back and I wrote quite a comprehensive answer explaining how a process can be used as a for loop in this way.

Here's a link to my answer of the other question. 
[Linkie](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57035/n-bit-shift-register-serial-in-serial-out-in-vhdl/57042#57042)

I've gone through your code and fixed it up a bit (and added a clock!). I haven't simulated it so it might not perform 100% timing wise, but it's an example to see what I mean in terms of using a process as a for loop and to get you onto the right track.

Here you go.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

-- unsigned types are part of the numeric_std package. They are like std_logic types, but have native support for +,-,*, etc.
package mypack is
    type x_vector is array(0 to 3) of unsigned(0 to 31);
    type y_vector is array(0 to 1) of unsigned(0 to 31);
    type f_vector is array(0 to 4) of unsigned(0 to 31);
end mypack;

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

use work.mypack.all;

entity convolution is 
port (
    clk : in std_logic;
    rst : in std_logic;
    x:in x_vector;
    y:in y_vector;
    f:out f_vector
);
end convolution;

architecture Behavioral of convolution is
    signal enable : std_logic;

    -- These are your for-loop count variables
    signal n_count : unsigned(0 to 4);
    signal k_count : unsigned(0 to 1);

    -- sum variable (you might want to look into making this 64 bits long, so the answer doesn't overflow)
    signal sum : unsigned (0 to 31);
begin

    -- process only executes when clock or reset changes
    convolve : process (clk,rst)
    begin
        if (rst = '1') then

            -- this is where you set your variables to 0;
            n_count <= (others => '0');
            k_count <= (others => '0');
            sum <= (others => '0');
            enable <= '0';

            -- nice way of setting all values in f array to zero (nest "others =>" for as many dimensions as you need)
            f <= (others => (others => '0'));

        elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
            -- if your n counter hits its max value ('high), reset the counter
            if (n_count = n_count'high) then
                n_count <= (others => '0');
                -- Add whatever you want to do when n hits it's max here...

            -- This is what is executed while n is counting up.
            else 

                -- if your k counter hits its max value ('high), reset the counter
                if (k_count = k_count'high) then
                    k_count <= (others => '0');
                    -- Add whatever you want it to do when k hits it's max here...

                -- This is what is executed while k is counting up (with n)
                else
                    -- This is where the actual convolution takes place.
                    -- The counters are converted to integers in order to be used as array references
                    sum <= sum + sum + (x(to_integer(k_count))*y(to_integer(n_count-k_count)));
                    -- Increment k!
                    k_count <= k_count + "1";
                end if;
                -- Increment n!
                n_count <= n_count + "1";

                -- I'm not hugely sure what you want to do with the enable, but this is where 
                -- it was in the other code.  
                enable <= '0';
                -- drive F with sum value
                f(to_integer(n_count)) <= sum;
                -- clear sum for next round.
                sum <= (others => '0');
            end if;
            -- enable again.
            enable <= '1';
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```